# Node.js - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am attempting to do an external GET request out to an endpoint requesting a general response of information. I have checked out a number of ways this can be done through node and have built the below request(some information such as hostname have been changed).

The problem I seem to run into that while my options are being declared and I am able to console.log them before the https.get command, once the https.get command is run I get the following error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')

Here is the code of the request

var https = require("https");

function getInformation()
{

```
var header = generateHeader();

console.log("header " + header);

const options = 
{
hostname: 'testUrlhere',
path: '/api/v1/partners',
port: '443',
headers: {'Authorization': header }
}


https.get(options,function(res){
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function(chunk){
    console.log('response:' + chunk)
    });
    
    });
```

}

From the code I am not identifying what might be causing the problem so any assistance would be appreciated as I am not used to Node.js

Comment: Looking on the error it seems like you have not imported the `https` module e.g. `import https from 'https'`?

Comment: that error means https is undefined, you probably need to define it with a require/import statement before you can use it

Comment: Hello, sorry I forgot to add in the above that I have var https = require("https");
 included in my code. Do I have to do an npm install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably not imported the `https` module prior to usage, try adding an import statement in the top of your file like this:

```
import https from 'https'
```

If you are using commonJS then try the following instead:

```
const https = require('node:https')
```